# É possivel usar folha de estilo em um aplicativo?

Tags: android, css

Estou começando um desenvolvimento no Eclipse, porém o estilo é muito feio, bordas, letras etc.

É possível utilizar CSS no Android?

Comment: Você quer estilizar o aplicativo que você está criando ou o eclipse?

Comment: Não tipo, exemplo eu quero estilizar o meu aplicativo.

Comment: usar fonts, cor, bordas, background etc. ?

Comment: tipo vamos supor existe uma maneira de utilizar que no caso seria  android:textColor="#ff0000" exemplo , eu queria saber se eu  posso chegar la e fazer <Style> </style> e começar o código ?

Comment: Alguma das respostas lhe resolveu o problema? Se sim, marque a resposta que mais lhe agrada como "Correta". Grato.

Comment: [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/3635)

Comment: Por favor @EdwardJunior, manifeste-se aqui: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4067/132

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Os `Views` do Android "não usam"/"não suportam" [StyleSheet (folha de estilo)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/styles.html) o que você pode alterar é o `textColor` o `typeface`, etc pelo XML do `View`.

Por exemplo:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#00FF00"
    android:typeface="monospace"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
```

### Style

Outra maneira de alterar que ficará semelhante ao CSS é usar o atributo `style=""`, assim:

```
<TextView
    style="@style/CodeFont"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
```

Este `@style/CodeFont` pode ser aplicado a vários "Views".

### Inheritance

Você também pode usar herança assim como é no CSS através do atributo `parent`:

```
<style name="GreenText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
</style>
```

Na tag `style` você pode usar o atributo `name` para herdar outros estilos de outras tags `style`. Seria algo como:

```
<style name="CodeFont">
...
</style>
```

Este vai herdar o `CodeFont` e a aplicar algo a mais

```
<style name="CodeFont.Red">
...
</style>
```

Este vai herdar o `CodeFont` e `CodeFont.Red` e a aplicar algo a mais

```
<style name="CodeFont.Red">
...
</style>
```

Porém ainda sim não conseguirá efeitos muito avançados

### Usando o WebView

Existe uma maneira de usar o `WebView` para criar aplicativos e assim usar CSS. Porém seus aplicativos serão quase totalmente em HTML.

Você precisa criar um `WebView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

E precisará habilitar o JavaScript:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Para carregar um arquivo dos resources use o caminho do url como `file:///android_asset/...`, exemplo:

```
myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/index.html");
```

Para carregar a folha de estilo, use algo como no seu html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:///android_asset/css/main.css">
```

Para carregar backgrounds no CSS, faça algo como:

```
body {
   background: url(file:///android_asset/images/bg.jpg);
}
```

Para entender como usar os resources leia: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/overview.html

### [Material Design](https://developer.android.com/design/material/index.html)

> Nota: Requer Android 5.0 (API level 21)

O Android agora possui o "Material Design" que pode lhe ajudar, leia [Creating Apps with Material Design](https://developer.android.com/training/material/index.html)

Você pode usar chamando:

- `@android:style/Theme.Material` (dark version)
- `@android:style/Theme.Material.Light` (light version)
- `@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar`

Usando herança para chamar o tema:

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <!-- Cores do tema -->

    <!--   Cores do appbar -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>

    <!--   variação "dark" para a barra de estado e o contexto das "barras de ferramentas" -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>

    <!--   Tema UI dos controles (tipo checkboxes e campos de texto) -->
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
  </style>
```

Por onde começar: https://developer.android.com/training/material/get-started.html

Answer (score 5):

Não é possível usar CSS em View's do Android puro. Se você usar `WebView` você pode é claro.

Mas você pode criar `Styles` que podem ser associadas as mesmas pelo atributo `android:style`, o que seria semelhante a um seletor/classe css. Mas essa estilização segue o padrão do android, com os atributos que você já usa.

Um exemplo seria:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CodeFont" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Para usar:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext"
    android:style="@style/CodeFont" <!-- "import" do estilo criado -->
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:text="@string/enter_text"
    android:inputType="text" />
```

Algumas referências:

- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html
- http://android-pro.blogspot.com.br/2010/08/using-themes-and-styles-in-android.html

Comment: obrigado pessoal