# Como criar "layouts responsivos" no Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou com dúvida de como criar um "Layout" responsivo para que sirva em todos os dispositivos smarts e tablets, para que o tamanho de textos, botões se adapte adequadamente para cada tela, qual a melhor maneira e prática para isto?

Aproveitando sobre o assunto, dando um exemplo referente ao framework javascript METEOR, nele você pode separar as "tags" html's por templates para não ficar o código grande e cada template ou .html você separa por pastas, é possivel fazer algo assim no Android?

Comment: Nada melhor do que ler a documentação: [Compatibilidade com várias telas](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), [Suporte para diferentes tamanhos de tela](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html) e [Como projetar para várias telas](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não creio que de para trabalhar como o *Meteor* no esquema no *Android*, mas o Android tem layouts que podem ser usados por include, por exemplo:

Seu Layout principal:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/app_bg"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <include android:id="@+id/news_title"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             layout="@layout/title" />

    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/hello"
              android:padding="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Seu layout reusável/reaproveitável:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/titlebar_bg">

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:src="@drawable/gafricalogo" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Leia sobre em:

- https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html
- https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/loading-ondemand.html

Existem também os Fragments, mas eles são um caso bem especifico https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

### Sobre a "Reponsividade"

Basicamente você terá que criar um Layout para cada tamanho, isto não é necessariamente "responsivo", mas funciona bem, você pode criar um layout para cada tela assim:

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml              // telas normais (por defeito/por padrão)
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml        // telas largas
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml       // telas muito largas
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml  // telas muito largas e em landscape
```

Mais detalhes em: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Ou você pode tentar a dica desta resposta no [*SOen*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21644072/1518921), se precisar fazer algo com tamanhos customizados que você deseja, um exemplo se a tela for maior que 600:

```
Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();

if (config.smallestScreenWidthDp >= 600) {
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity_tablet); //activity para tablets
} else {
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity); //activity normal
}
```

---

### WebView como aplicativo

Existe também a possibilidade usar `WebView` parar criar um WebApp, mas realmente nem sempre compensa (vai depender muito do caso), todavia se desejar usar o *Meteor*, *Bootstrap* e afins pode tentar esta resposta:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/50679/3635